# restart program if it outputs some string

Tags: bash, shell

I want to loop  a process in a bash script, it is a process which should run forever but which sometimes fails.

When it fails, it outputs `>>747;3R` to its last line, but keeps running.

I tried (just for testing)

```
while [ 1 ]
do
  mono Program.exe
  last_pid=$!
  sleep 3000
  kill $last_pid
done
```

but it doesn't work at all, the process `mono Program.exe` just runs forever (until it crashes, but even then my script does nothing.)

Comment: Fix the mono process

Comment: what is in `$1`? The pid of the last command is `$!`

Comment: @123 whoops, typo in question.

Comment: @minseong, the process is likely "handling" the `TERM` signal. You should whether fix the signal handler, or make a second attempt with `KILL` signal: `kill -9 $last_pid`

Comment: Does `mono Program.exe` place itself in the background? If not, you need to run it asynchronously (in the background) with `&`.

Comment: Maybe you could change the script to let the program write into a FIFO and store the PID in a variable. As Jens mentioned, this should run in the background (by using `$`), Then you could consume the FIFO content in a loop -- whenever the pattern you've described above is detected, you could execute kill -9 $PID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$! expands to the PID of the last process started in the background.      This can be seen with:

```
cat test
sleep 2
lastpid=$!
echo $lastpid

~$ bash -x test
+ sleep 2
+ lastpid=
+ echo
```

vs

```
~$ cat test
sleep 2 &
lastpid=$!
echo $lastpid

:~$ bash -x test
+ lastpid=25779
+ sleep 2
+ echo 25779
```

The fixed version of your script would read:

```
while true; do
  mono Program.exe &
  last_pid=$!
  sleep 3000
  kill $last_pid
done
```

Your version was running mono Program.exe and then sitting there.  It didn't make it to the next line as it was waiting for the process to finish.  Your kill command then didn't work as $! never populated (wasn't a background process).